# Multiple SET statements in SQL trigger using CASE?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a table in my SQL database that includes a column called 'event_attributes.' It is a string and each cell holds something like this:

```
a:4{s:10:"Discipline";s:7:"Running";s:5:"Level";s:3:"All";s:10:"Instructor";s:13:"Bill Jones";s:3:"Free";s:2:"No";}
```

I am trying to create a trigger that breaks this down into several new columns that look like

```
Disciple |  Level |  Instructor  |   Free
-----------------------------------------
Running  |  All   |  Bill Jones  |   No
```

Using the code below, I can get this to work for ONE set statement.

```
 DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `recode`;
 CREATE TRIGGER `recode` 
 BEFORE INSERT ON `wp_em_events` 
 FOR EACH ROW 
 SET NEW.discipline = CASE 
 WHEN NEW.event_attributes LIKE '%Boxing%' THEN 'Boxing' 
 WHEN NEW.event_attributes LIKE '%Climbing%' THEN 'Climbing' 
 WHEN NEW.event_attributes LIKE '%Cycling%' THEN 'Cycling'
 WHEN NEW.event_attributes LIKE '%Yoga%' THEN 'Yoga'   
 ELSE NEW.discipline = NULL 
 END
```

However, If I add something like:

```
 SET NEW.level = CASE

 WHEN NEW.event_attributes LIKE '%All%' THEN 'All'

 ....
```

I get a message saying there is an error with my SQL syntax. Anyone know how to nest two or more SET statements into one trigger? Sorry if this is a stupid question - new at this.

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of adding additional `set` statements, I think you should be using commas -- `set new.field = blah, new.field2 = blah2`...

Comment: this line has a problem. `ELSE NEW.discipline = NULL `, it should be `ELSE NULL` instead.or you can omit the `ELSE` part as the default is `null` if all the conditions fail

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a comma to list multiple fields.  Here's a condensed example:

```
create trigger test before insert on sometable
for each row 
set NEW.field2 = case when New.field1 = 1 then 2 else 0 end, 
    NEW.field3 = case when New.field1 = 1 then 3 else 0 end;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa8a8/1)

Btw, although your `else` statement technically works, you're basically setting `NEW.discipline = NEW.discipline = NULL`.  Using `else null` reads a little better.

Comment: Thanks all! Yes, that comma is what did it. Another problem I had was I was adding another "SET," so it looked like SET NEW.field1.... , SET NEW.field2..... Added the comma, dropped the second "SET" and it works! I have also changed that ELSE NEW.field = NULL to ELSE NULL. Appreciate the help!